# Expose GlassFish Log file (server.log) via http in the browser

Tags: java, maven, http, glassfish, teamcity

I would like to know if its possible for me to expose server.log over http, like i would like to see my logs on the Internet browser. like how the Team City build work, the Build output are shown on the browser; can I `tail -f /path/to/glassfish/domains/YOURDOMAIN/logs/server.log` and specify the port and URL to access via a browser like `tail -f /path/to/glassfish/domains/YOURDOMAIN/logs/server.log -host localhost -port 9090 -path /glassfish/logs`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access you log through the following address:

```
https://www.yourservername.com:4848/management/domain/view-log
```

Comment: You are welcome. I too had to find that and I did a python program for getting and parsing it. You can get more information on it (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24928/general-administration.htm#GSADG0030) Please mark the answer as right and upvote it.

Comment: Taj Masindi, please mark answer as right if that really worked very well for you. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can view server logs through the GlassFish admin console.

Open the admin console on https://hostname:4848 and click on `server (Admin Server)`. You should see a button that says `View Log Files`. If you click on that, you should be able to view the log files as shown in my screenshot of Payara Server below:

[image: The admin console log viewer]